# Reset expanding text-area's height on form submit

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this script which auto expands the text area height based on the amount of content you type into it.

```
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
  o.style.height = "1px";
  o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
}

<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

This works great for increasing/decreasing the height depending on the content entered. However I would like it to fully reset to default height once you hit enter / submit the form. (its a chat application). Currently you have to begin typing new text after the form is submitted before it recognizing the new appropriate height. (its a lil chat app)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Editing my question right now. I just realized it does decrease in height as you remove text so my only issue is resetting the text-box height default when pressing enter/submitting the form.

Comment: Do you want it to be at default when the text is a certain length or empty?

Comment: I want it to default to a specific height when empty, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check in your JavaScript for the length of the value of the textarea, like this:

```
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
  o.style.height = "1px";
  o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";

  if(o.value.length < 1){
    o.style.height = "30px";
  };

}
```

Here's a working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNBLPZ)